# How to load test REST WCF service?

Tags: wcf, rest, load-testing

How can i load test REST WCF service?

Is it possible with Web performance testing and Load testing in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Please help. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This knowledgebase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231282) has information on the tools available for stress testing web apps from Microsoft. I've used the Web Capacity Analysis Tool mentioned there in the past.

You can also look at the [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.net) plugin [stresstimulus](http://stresstimulus.stimulustechnology.com/). I've used fiddler for non load testing, but I have not used the stresstimulus plugin.

Comment: StresStimulus did exactly what I wanted within 15 minutes. I'm not certain that this is the best tool to build a long term load testing strategy but it's definitely a great starting point for someone looking to quickly find out how his or her application behaves under load

Answer (score 2):

Disclosure: I work for StresStimulus maker. 
In case you need to test with more than 250 users allowed by VS 2010 Ultimate, you can still record HTTP sessions in Fiddler, as described by @Nat, and then use StresStimulus for load testing in Fiddler. StresStimulus is not nearly as complete as VS 2010 Ultimate, but it’s free and you can check if it’s sufficient for your case. You can parameterize requests using .CSV files and load test with up to 1500 virtual users per client.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, a WCF web service still relies on good old http calls.

You are not really going to be able to record the webtest the same as for a webpage, but [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler2/version.asp) will allow you to record the http calls made, so fire fiddler and then use the interface for your service to record some actions.

You can then save the fiddler http calls as a webtest for Visual Studio.

I personally would turn the test into a coded test so that items in the Webservice can be parameterised nicely, but it depends on what you need to do. Once a test is recorded, you can easily change the base url to point it to pre-production test environments or whatever is required.

Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate is a really nice tool for load testing and with 250 virtual users available for load testing, you can simulate a lot of actual users with it.